# Some image editor apps do not accept provided URI through intent

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

I'm trying to send the result of an intent (which is the `URI` of selected media on my app) back to the caller app as I choose my app from provided dialog to select a media. For most of the apps it works flawlessly but on some apps like Pixlr it says `cannot open the image`. Is there anything else that I should add to the intent to send back the `URI` that is requested from other apps correctly to cover some specific apps too?

This is my `intent filter`:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
    <data android:mimeType="video/*" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.OPENABLE" />
    <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
    <data android:mimeType="video/*" />
</intent-filter>
```

, this is the way I'm trying to send result of picking media from my app:

```
Intent pickResultIntent = new Intent().setData(mediaContentUri);
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, pickResultIntent);
finish();
```

and this is the way I'm getting mediaUri:

```
mediaContentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
    mediaId);
```

Comment: What exactly is the valid of `mediaUri`? Is this pointing to some `FileProvider` of yours? Most likely, you need to add `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` to `pickResultIntent`.

Comment: Correct. After adding `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` problem solved. How is that some apps do not need this flag?

Comment: Since I do not know what `mediaUri` is, I cannot answer that question.

Comment: Sorry my bad. `mediaUri` is `mediaContentUri`. I've got it with the provided method in the question and I've got `mediaId` by querying the `ContentResolver`.

Comment: I am not quite certain why you are getting mixed results from the `Uri`. `MediaStore` is a bit weird from a permission standpoint. My best guess is that failing apps do not have `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, and you are extending them that right to this specific `Uri`, but that's just a guess.

Answer (score 0):

Answered in [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41200783/some-image-editor-apps-do-not-accept-provided-uri-through-intent#comment69601463_41200783) by [CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware)

```
Intent pickResultIntent = new Intent().setData(mediaContentUri);
pickResultIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, pickResultIntent);
finish();
```